# SQL Server - Date is converted to integer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am exporting data from `Excel` to `SQL Server` through an API. Everything is supposed to save as `nvarchar` but date is stored as `int` value (automatically). How can I keep, in `SQL table`, date value as it is i.e. like `01/01/1990` instead of 32874.

Might be a basic question, Googled and looked into SO but couldn't find what I am after yet. Help appreciated!

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: asp.net web api is used to save data

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can convert to a date by using:

```
select dateadd(day, 32874, '1899-12-31')
```

There is probably also a way to fix this when importing the data, by treating it as an actual date or string.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but data is not validated, value may not be a valid Date. So just wanna push to DB Table as it is (nvarchar) either it's date or not.

Comment: @Sami . . . If it is really a string, then nothing would convert it to a number.  You should turn the column into a string -- perhaps by using `text()`.